# SQL Server getting first result before given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to write this query.

```
start_date -> '2017-08-02 00:00:00.000'
end_date -> '2017-08-03 00:00:00.000'
```

I need the first date value before both `start_date` and `end_date` and put it in the query to list records in the table which are between these dates (1 record before original as I explained)

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    table_cons
WHERE 
    (SELECT TOP 1
         fld_Id, fld_ConsStartDateTime
     FROM table_cons
     WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime < N'2017-08-02 00:00:00.000'
     ORDER BY fld_ConsStartDateTime DESC)
     AND (SELECT TOP 1
              fld_Id, fld_ConsEndDateTime
          FROM table_cons
          WHERE fld_ConsEndDateTime < N'2017-08-03 00:00:00.000'
          ORDER BY fld_ConsEndDateTime DESC)
```

Error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Any help is appriciated.

**UPDATE**

- Start_date = '2017-08-02 00:00:000'
- End_date   = '2017-08-03 00:00:000'

Normally what I would do is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime > 'Start_date' 
  AND fld_ConsEndDateTime < 'End_date'
```

But this is not the case. I need to calculate new `Start_date` and `End_date` (let's say `Start_date2` and `End_date2`). How to calculate thesenew dates? By fetching from the db the first datetimes before given dates)

Like so:

- Start_date2 -> '2017-08-01 23:55:00.000'
- End_date2 -> '2017-08-02 23:55:00.000'

Comment: Do you mean you need 1 row with date before start_date and 1 row with date before end_date?

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I need the 1 record before given  dates. For example 
start_date = 2017-08-02 00:00.000, If the first date before this date in the database is 2017-08-01 23:59:00 000., I need that date

Comment: it's not 100% clear what you want. you want to have the record where BOTH (startdate & enddate) are bevore a given date? or before two given dates (as your post shows)? please add example data to make it clear to everybody.

Comment: @EstebanP. I updated the question, I hope it's making sense to you now

Answer (score 0):

If you need calculate new datetimes with -5 minutes you could do this:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, '2017-08-02 00:00:000')
DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, '2017-08-03 00:00:000')
```

As side note you cannot place query **as condition** you can put it **in condition**. In other words you cannot do this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table_cons
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1
  fld_Id,
  fld_ConsStartDateTime
FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime < N'2017-08-02 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY fld_ConsStartDateTime DESC)
```

but you can do this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime  <= (SELECT TOP 1
  fld_Id,
  fld_ConsStartDateTime
FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime < N'2017-08-02 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY fld_ConsStartDateTime DESC)
```

However this wouldn't make any sense since you can just limit your query directly.

Comment: Please see the updte part. I've tried to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

i understand your question like hat:

You want to select the first entry (newest or oldest one?) which is between your data range.
the result then would be for example 10 entries each to a different timestamp.
So my understanding.

You could filter on the data range and select the min(date)(if it has to be the oldest entry) or max(date) for the newest entry as subquery and use that for another query to filter on exact equality to the min(date) / max(date).
So maybe something like that for the oldest entry

```
    select * from table_cons where fld_ConsStartDateTime=
    (
         select min(fld_ConsStartDateTime) FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime > 'Start_date' 
  AND fld_ConsEndDateTime < 'End_date'
    )
and fld_ConsEndDateTime =
    (
         select min(fld_ConsEndDateTime ) FROM table_cons
WHERE fld_ConsStartDateTime > 'Start_date' 
  AND fld_ConsEndDateTime < 'End_date'
    )
```